# How to make a grid based layout design responsive?

Tags: css, grid-layout, plone-4.x

I am trying to make the design of my website https://take-note.com responsive. I was able to get most of it done except for a part that uses a grid based layout. There are 4 columns of images at the bottom of the page titled "notes", "memes", "field notes" and "front page news". I would like these to appear one below the other on a narrow mobile device. I tried to set the width to 100% but that does not seem to do it.

Any advice from CSS gurus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the media query here like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div.cell {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

This will make the 4 columns to be below one another in devices with width less then 768px; you can adjust this accordingly to target devices as per your use case